# How can I pay the player only one time once he/she has passed GO in Monopoly?

Tags: java

I was thinking if statement, but I am not sure how it would work..

```
if(user.position >= gameBoard[0])     //user.position is the player position on the board
          passGo = true;
```

But this would set off for anything over 0. So how can I make it flag once they pass go then cancel?

Comment: What *exactly* is `user.position`?

Comment: user.position is the position of the player on the board.

Comment: @David that is actually not as easy as it seems to check if you passed gameBoard[0] based only on previous position, and current position. Consider "go back 3 spaces". Sure you could limit it to only moving 12 spaces forward, but then it fails for "advance to reading railroad"

Comment: @Cruncher: Indeed, there would definitely be more domain logic at work here.  It's a start, though.  Much of this logic is going to depend on the game mechanics surrounding movement, with which we're unfamiliar.  For example, does the player *cross* the spaces when moving, or is he just directly transported to the destination?  The rules of Monopoly make a distinction between those two, but I'm guessing the logic of this code does not.  Therein may lie the problem.

Comment: @David, Cruncher: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I am only concerned with the player passing the space.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus how do you represent `user.position` exactly? Is boardwalk 39 and go is 0? Jail 10, parking 20, go to jail 30?

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus: Consider what "passing" means, then.  And carefully examine the rules and gameplay of Monopoly in that regard.  If you set `user.position` to the destination space, then the user didn't "pass" Go.  If, instead, you loop between the current `user.position` and the new `user.position` and apply game rules for each iteration of the loop, you can apply the rules for Go in that loop.

Comment: @Cruncher: Yes, I am using the value of the user.position to see which space it relates to in the Array.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus so user.position is a number, and gameBoard[0] is what? An object? how are you comparing these?

Comment: @David that's what I noticed in the answer below. It was a simple case of comparing the previous position to the new position.

Comment: @Cruncher, sorry for the confusion. I figured it out with what isnot2bad and David said. It was figuring out the logic in how to note that someone has passed a certain position. Thanks again sorry for any confusion .

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus: Ignore my original (now deleted) comment.  Cruncher is right, the logic is more complex than that.  I've supplied a new answer below to begin addressing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you roll the dice:

```
user.position += diceRoll;
if(user.position >= 40)
{
    //award $200
    user.position -= 40;
}
```

This is simple stuff to deal with the dice roll. You then need to just program each of the chance cards individually. Don't do all of your position checks at beginning/end of turn. It becomes very convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

The user has passed GO, if he has been before GO at the beginning of the move and after GO at the end of the move. So consider recording the previous position too...

Comment: Consider "Go back 3 spaces". 3 back is 37 forward.

Comment: This makes sense. I knew it was something simple. I can use the boolean to flag whether he has passed or not, and not have to worry about multiple payouts if I am comparing previous position to current position.

Comment: @Cruncher I don't know Monopoly in detail. I just wanted to give a hint. Of course a similar strategy works the other way round, when moving back.

Comment: Go back 3 spaces is just a special card. You only need to test for passing Go in the dice/movement routine and cards that move forward. It really is as simple as implementing the logic of when you should be awarded the $200

Answer (score 0):

Considering the rules and gameplay of Monopoly, understand that the game itself makes a distinction between moving across spaces and teleporting directly to a space.  (For example, "Go directly to Jail.  Do not pass Go, do not collect $200.")

So if your code is doing this, then you're missing that part of Monopoly:

```
user.position = newposition;
```

Instead, consider looping between the user's current position and the new position.  In pseudo-code, something more like this:

```
while (user.position != newposition) {
    // move the user to the next position
    // apply the rules for that position
    // in special cases where movement is interrupted, break out of the loop
}
```

In this scenario, you'd apply game logic in every iteration of the loop.  If the "current" position in the loop is Go, then you apply the logic of collecting $200.  In cases where the user is "transported" (going directly to Jail, for example), the loop is interrupted by changing `user.position` to the Jail position explicitly, so the loop never crosses Go.

This way you're not burying yourself in the math and logic of trying to figure out where the user was, where the user is, and what happened in between.  Instead you're moving from space to space and applying the game's rules along the way.

Comment: I don't think too much happens "in between". `while (user.position != newposition) {
    // move the user to the next position` This still fails for "go back 3 spaces" as well. You would need to specify the direction that you're moving.

I programmed monopoly about 5 years back, so I know the caveats, and problems.

Comment: I'll work with it. Just needed a head start on thinking about how the computer would know. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Cruncher: Sure, the direction may need to be part of it as well.  There's an over-arching context of the "purpose" of the move.  "Go back 3 spaces" would be a specific command, as opposed to just "normal dice-driven movement."  The step in which logic is applied for the current space should check for that state.  If the user is moving as a result of a condition in the X set of conditions, apply Rule A, if it's in the Y set of conditions, apply Rule B, and so on.